# safe way to get the n-th element of a union

Tags: c++, templates, unions

I am writing a variant class(yes i know about std::variant, its just for fun), and this is what i have so far

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
union Variant<First, Rest...>
{
    template<size_t N>
    using Types = typename Type<N, First, Rest...>::_Type;
    First first;
    Variant<Rest...> rest;
    uint16_t activeIndex;

    template<size_t N>
    Types<N>& get()
    {
        
    }

};
```

the Type struct just allows me to find the type of the n-th element.
I know that all the union's members are at the same memory address so can i just

```
return *(Types<N>*)&first
```

in the get function? is this safe?
or is there some other way to do this.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you essentially want to know is if the operation:

```
*(Types<N>*)&first
```

adheres to [strict aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object). The answer is yes, so long as the type returned by `Types<N>` is a [compatible type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Compatible_types):

> The types T and U are compatible, if they are the same type (same name or aliases introduced by a typedef)

In your example i am guessing that this is passed onto the user in some way by saying that the value must be set and retrieved using the same type. If this is the case and the user adheres to this rule, then it is safe.

If you want to go above and beyond, you can look at the implementation of `std::variant`. The [`std::variant::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) function actually *throws* if you try to retrieve a value that was not set correctly. To achieve this, you could think of using the reverse of `Types<N>` to get the index, and store it when setting. Then check that this is the index you are using when you `get`, if they are not the same, then throw.

Comment: Thanks, but what type does Types<N> have to be compatible with?

Comment: Whatever it was last set with.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox You explain things very well. Thanks from me too.

Comment: The problem isn't strict aliasing (since no objects are being aliased) but whether `*(Types<N>*)&first` (or `reinterpret_cast<Types<N>&>(first)`) produces a valid reference to `this->rest.rest.....first`, which requires them to be [pointer-interconvertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible), which luckily for union types they are. But if you add one struct type in between and one of your types is non standard-layout, this no longer works without `std::launder` (like `*std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Types<N>*>(this))`)

Comment: @Artyer  So if i had Variant<float, std::string> they wouldn't be pointer-interconvertible? They have the same memory address don't they? if not, should i use *std::launder((Types<N>*)&first>, or the constexpr recursion method?

Comment: @Artyer i did some more research and i found this website https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.union, here it says that if you have a union, the union object is pointer-interconvertible with all of its non static data members, is this right? So could I just cast ```this``` to ```Types<N>```?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox this worked fine, but I just now turned up the optimization to O3 and now I a warning saying I might be violating strict aliasing ```Main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Variant<First, Rest ...>::Types<N>& Variant<First, Rest ...>::get() [with long unsigned int N = 2; First = int; Rest = {bool, float, long long int, unsigned int}; Variant<First, Rest ...>::Types<N> = float]’:
Main.cpp:85:14:   required from here
Main.cpp:70:29: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer might break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   70 |         return *(Types<N>*)&first;```

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo This case is fine because unions are pointer interconvertible with all their members, so you don't need to `std::launder`, but in very similar cases you might have to. That warning is also just warning you that it might be wrong, but no strict-aliasing rules have been broken so you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Compared to directly using address type casting, another way is to use recursion.

In order to reduce the depth of recursion, you can use multiple `if constexpr` branches to stop the recursion early.

```
template<size_t N>
Types<N>& get() const {
  if constexpr (N == 0)
    return first;
  else if constexpr (N == 1)
    return rest.first;
  else if constexpr (N == 2)
    return rest.rest.first;
  else
    return rest.rest.rest.template get<N - 3>();
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/M9es6KGee)

Comment: is there any advantage to using this over the accepted answer? also how does the syntax ```rest.rest.rest template. get<N-3>();```  work?

Comment: This will increase your compile time, what is the advantage?

Comment: Address casting is not a type-safe and "modern" way, it is more like a C solution.

Comment: @康桓瑋 is there a modern and safe way to do address cast in c++? should i use static_cast instead? it may not be safe but i don't want to increase by compile time right now.

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo. Variant is implemented using *recursive* union. The compile-time overhead caused by `get` that reduces the recursive depth is not worth mentioning. I don't think that it can bring observable compile-time costs when the number of alternatives is not extremely large.

Comment: Also, if you refer to [MSVC-STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/variant#L561), [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant#L306) and [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/variant#L447)'s implementation of `variant::get`, you will find that they also use *recursion* instead of unsafe address casting.

Comment: And the biggest reason: This is `constexpr`